# anaconda virtualenv name doesn't show up

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, prompt, powerline

here are my powerline and conda info.
[image]
i tried `plugin = ( virtualenv)` and

```
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status virtualenv)
```

etc. these attempts  by editing in ~/.zshrc but not works for me

I guess that this part has problem.
my oh-my-zsh doesn't recognized variable $VIRTUAL_ENV..
[image]

if I edit $VIRTUAL_ENV as aaaa
then result is below

[image]

there are anyone help?

Comment: It sounds like you might be confusing `virtualenv` with Conda environments. They are two distinct things. Use one or the other, but don't mix them. If you run `conda init zsh`, it should enable auto-modification of the `PS1` variable (i.e., the prompt text).

Comment: Thank you I understood this situation. how can i fix it for auto-modification of the PS1 variable?